# Creating glsl library

Tags: glsl, data-structure

I have different functions for example normalmapping which I use all the time...
Now I thought about making a small glsl library.

My problem:
I don't want to have all functions within the same "namespace".

I would like to have it like:

```
vec4 lighting::Phong(vec3 normal, vec3 color, vec3 lightPositionRelative)
```

The thing is, that I have tons of functions and sometimes multiple functions are related to the same thing, for example: A HashTable, AddKey, GetKey, HasKey...

So some kind of namespace or even better a class like structure.
What are the options I have?
How are you guys handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GLSL does not support C++ style namespaces. You might want to do some regex magic before parsing the shader, replacing '::' with '_' or something. You might want to have a preprocessor of sorts - or just forget about it entirely.